# styles css in embeded souncloud player

Tags: css, iframe, embed, soundcloud

I am trying to make a small site I use embed code to display soundcloud music in webpage.
however, I want to remove the orange button play and the player down my iframe .
I am researching I found that I could do it with css, just hidden buttons .
So I created a style css in my page but all the styles are included except that relating to the frame soundcloud .
could someone help me?
because when I make changes directly on the page with inspect element it works.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @djodev, you should start by posting here what code you have tried. Then someone can help you figure out why it isn't working.

Comment: this is my code :  <iframe width="100%" height="450" scrolling="no" frameborder="no"  src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/139359277&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_playcount=false&amp;show_comments=false&amp;show_user=false&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true&amp;buying=false&amp;sharing=false"></iframe>

Comment: the problem is that the frame come with the soundcloud css and dont take my css style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CSS` you are writing on your CSS file wont effect content of iFrame.

Solutions:

1. Do you really need an iFrame? Cant it be done using modal window or something like that?
2. Add CSS you want to add using JS/JQuery 
   `$('iframe').load( function() {
   $('iframe').contents().find("head")
     .append($("<style type='text/css'>  .my-class{display:none;}  </style>"));
   });`

Comment: i havenn't head in my iframe.it's just a frame for taking tracks on soundcloud like this : <iframe width="100%" height="450" scrolling="no" frameborder="no"  src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/139359277&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_playcount=false&amp;show_comments=false&amp;show_user=false&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true&amp;buying=false&amp;sharing=false"></iframe>

Comment: You have to add it in iframe's head(inside iFrame). It will be available after it is loaded.

Comment: i dont understand what you want to say @Shishir Trivedi, to create a new head tag or to add just the css code in my iframe ?

Comment: @djodev - You have to catch the existing `head` element of the content of you iFrame using javascript like the example i gave. Then add style you want add by appending  it (see the example above). If you can share the your code, i might be able to explain more effectively.

Comment: this is my code : $(document).ready(function(){
    $('iframe').contents().find("head")
            .append($("<style type='text/css'> .waveform__layer {display: none;}   </style>"));
    });});  but i dont sure that are the best classe because i test many class and that doesn't work.

Comment: See there is the problem. When you are writing it on $(document).ready its referring to your webpage not the the document inside webpage. So use $('iframe').load( function() instead. try it once.

Comment: i do that : 
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('iframe').load(function () {
            $('iframe').contents().find("head")
                .append($("<style type='text/css'> .sceneLayer ,  .waveform__layer{display: none;}  {}   </style>"));
        });

    }); but that doesn't work anymore

Comment: Can you share your working code? As in your webpage? I'll try to fix and give you a solution. Or else just look up how to append style in iFrame : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709234/cant-create-style-tag-in-iframe-head

Comment: my code is in local. i retry iframe code from a form and i display that in my page now i want after displaying that to hide some button. this is the code : <?php
                while($test = $req->fetch()){
                echo '<div  class="actu" style="width: 25%; display: inline-block; margin: 2%;">
                    <span id="frame">'.$test['lien'].'</span></div>';
                    ?>
                <?php }
                ?>